# Encrypt with Node.js AES CTR and decrypt with PyCrypto

Tags: python, node.js, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

Okay, so basically I am having issues decrypting with Python.

I've managed to encrypt/decrypt data with Node.js - using "aes-128-ctr", the same goes for PyCrypto, but when I try to encrypt with Node.js and decrypt with Python I get invalid deciphered text.

Node.js code:

```
var key = "1234567890123456";
var cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes-128-ctr",key)
var ctext = cipher.update('asasasa','utf8','hex') +  cipher.final('hex')
console.log(ctext) // outputs: "f2cf6ecd8f"
```

Python code:

```
counter = Counter.new(128)
cipher = AES.new("1234567890123456", AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
cipher.decrypt("f2cf6ecd8f") // outputs: weird encoding characters
```

By the way, I don't care about the level of security of this encryption, I care about performance more.

Comment: Is 'asasasa' the data to be encrypted, 7-characters? If so the output in CTR mode should be 7-bytes, 14 bytes in hex. But the output is "f2cf6ecd8f" which is 5-bytes hex encoded. This is a give-away that there is an error in the usage. Also what is the counter initial value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crypto.createCipher` takes a password and uses `EVP_BytesToKey` internally to derive a key and IV from that. Contrary to that, pycrypto directly expects a key and IV. You need to use exactly the same procedure on both sides.

`crypto.createCipher` must never be used with CTR-mode, because the key and IV generation are not randomized. Since the CTR-mode is a streaming mode, it will always produce the same key stream which might enable an attacker who *only* observes multiple ciphertexts that are encrypted with the same password to deduce the plaintext. This is possible because of the resulting many-time pad issue.

If you must use CTR-mode, then you have to use `crypto.createCipheriv`. If you use the same key, you have to use a different IV every time. This is why this is actually called a nonce for CTR-mode. For AES-CTR, a nonce of 96 bit is a good compromise between security and size of possibly encryptable plaintexts.

```
var plaintext = 'asasasa'
var key = "1234567890123456" # don't use this one!
var nonce = crypto.randomBytes(12)
var iv = Buffer.concat([nonce, Buffer.alloc(4, 0)])
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-ctr", key, iv)
var ciphertext = nonce.toString('hex') + cipher.update(plaintext,'utf8','hex') +  cipher.final('hex')
console.log(ciphertext)
```

Example output:

```
5b88aeb265712b6c8bfa8dbd63012d1e52eb42
```

The IV is not secret and you have to use the exact same IV during decryption. Usually, it is sent along with the ciphertext by being prefixed to it. It is then sliced off before decryption:

```
ct = codecs.decode('5b88aeb265712b6c8bfa8dbd63012d1e52eb42', 'hex') # I'm using Python 3
counter = Counter.new(32, prefix=ct[:12], initial_value=0)
cipher = AES.new("1234567890123456", AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
cipher.decrypt(ct[12:])
```

Output:

```
b'asasasa'
```

---

Keep in mind that a key needs to be randomly chosen. You can generate a random key and keep it in an encoded form in the source code (i.e. as Hex). If you do that, you must not give the source code or the bytecode to anyone that you wouldn't trust the key with.

Comment: Thanks Artjom, I appreciate your answer, I marked it as correct.
I wanted to ask regarding `counter = Counter.new(32, prefix=ct[:12], initial_value=0)`, I'd like to understand why you'd choose this prefix and how the 32 int makes the difference? Regarding the rest of the things, I must admit that I had an understanding by going through the git & other resources, also here on SO, but I didn't have the proficiency in cryptography and PyCrypto to come up with that counter, I'd be happy to understand better, how it works. Again, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The main thing about CTR mode you have to understand is that the same counter value must not ever be used when you use the same key. The AES block size is 128 bits long which means that the counter in CTR mode must have the same size. There are different ways to think about what the counter is. Usually, we're talking about a fixed part of bits *x* and the variable part of bits *128 - x*. The fixed part is usually set to 96 random bits when starting to encrypt a message, because it is sufficiently improbable to get the same prefix for multiple encryptions....

Comment: When the prefix is set, then the remaining bits (128-96=32) can be used to increase the counter for each block that is encrypted. For AES, that means that 68 GB or data can be encrypted before you need a new prefix (2^32 * 128 bit). If you need to encrypt more data in a single pass, you can use a 88 bit prefix and a 40 bit counter. You can't decrease the prefix length arbitrarily. You have to think about how many messages you want to encrypt. For example, if you want to encrypt more than 4 billion messages, then a prefix of 64 bit will not be enough due to the birthday problem.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated explanation

Comment: Thanks for this amazing explanation and solution. was looking for it for about a day.